# Power Query .SelectRows filter based on a list

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I created a query which I want to be able to filter based on a column from another table, how can I achieve this as it doesn't seem to work?

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data("https://login.salesforce.com/", [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    MyCustomObject = Source{[Name="MyCustomObject "]}[Data],
    accnt = Source{[Name="Account"]}[Data],
    accntId = Table.SelectColumns(accnt, {"Id"}),
    accntList = Table.ToList(accntId, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",")),
    #"Filtered" =  Table.SelectRows(MyCustomObject, each List.Contains(accntList, [AccountId__c]))

 in 
    #"Filtered"
```

I've also tried using `List.Contains(accnt[Id])` but no joy

If I changed it to `each (AccountId__c = "Some Value Here")` it works but not with a list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the IDs unique in each column? If so, you can do a Merge with an Inner Join Kind, which you can do through the UI (in the Home ribbon tab) if you put `MyCustomObject` and `accnt` into separate queries.

If the IDs are not unique, you can still do a Merge, but you'll have to do one of the Outer Join Kinds, expand the new column, and then filter out the column with the null ID.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in the line:

```
accntList = Table.ToList(accntId, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",")),
```

I use to transform the field in a list with this line:

```
accntList = List.Distinct(accnt[Id]),
```

The code will be something like:

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data("https://login.salesforce.com/", [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    MyCustomObject = Source{[Name="MyCustomObject "]}[Data],
    accnt = Source{[Name="Account"]}[Data],
    accntList = List.Distinct(accnt[Id]),
    #"Filtered" =  Table.SelectRows(MyCustomObject, each List.Contains(accntList, [AccountId__c]))

 in 
    #"Filtered"
```